# How to enable post code entry text box in flutter-stripe plugin?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

currently, we using bellow packages in a flutter to use stripe as our paymentgateway,

https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment

if we compare flutter integration with a web interface (laravel-stripe) ( stipe intent ),
there are 2 different

a) In Web there is an option to enable "postcode" so that users can type postcode but in flutter-stripe packages, it's missing.

b) in laravel-stripe, when there are some issues with stripe i.e (not sufficient fund or postcode validation issues, we get clear messages back from the stripe,
however, in stripe-flutter plugin we just get basic "payment declined"

my question is,
a) Can we enable postcode entry when using a flutter-stripe plugin?
b) when using fluter-stipe plugin, can we get more detailed message from stripe when a payment fails?

Please let me know
we are about to go live but now we realized these two issues

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Flutter, but you may want to ask other users in the [issues for the repository](https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment/issues). Note that this package is a port of `tipsi-stripe`, and links to [its docs](https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/tree/experimental-connect/website/docs-md) for examples.

You can see [this doc describing creating a payment method](https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/blob/experimental-connect/website/docs-md/paymentMethod.md) including billing details.